# Mathematica: Why am I getting the Tag Times is protected error?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

```
f[t_, y_] := 26*y*(1 - y);    
y0 = 0.5; numsteps = 20;   
dt = 0.1; t = t0; y = y0;          
thelist = List[{t0, y0}];   
Do[ k1 = f[t, y]; t = t + dt; yp = y + dt* k1;k2 = f[t, yp];
y = y + 0.05*(k1 + k2);
thelist = Append[thelist, {t, y}];, {i, 1, numsteps} ];
```

I keep getting the error message "Set:Tag Times in Do[k1] is Protected." and I cant figure out why.

Comment: restart your kernel

Comment: why are defining function `f[t_, y_] := 26*y*(1 - y);` that takes `t` as argument, but do not use it in the function?

Answer (score 1):

This error message is telling you that you cannot use that function name because you already used it.
You can use Clear, `Clear[k1]`.

More information: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EsXJkCh8OaY